# Is there a way to call std::equal_range with a std::function instead of a structure?

Tags: c++, function-object

In the below example a `struct Comp` is created. Is there a way to make it a `std::function` or write the comparator itself while calling `std::equal_range`? Can I get rid of the `struct`?

```
struct Comp
{
    bool operator() ( const S& s, int i ) const { return s.number < i; }
    bool operator() ( int i, const S& s ) const { return i < s.number; }
};
     
const auto p2 = std::equal_range(vec.begin(),vec.end(), 2, Comp{});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `boost::hana::overload` to overload lambdas:

```cpp
    auto constexpr comp = boost::hana::overload(
        []( const S& s, int i ) { return s.number < i; },
        []( int i, const S& s ) { return i < s.number; }
    );

    const auto p2 = std::equal_range(vec.begin(),vec.end(), 2, comp);
```

Obviously you can put the whole `boost::hana::overload(…)` thing in the call to `std::equal_range`, but it just makes the code less readable, imho.

However, I would stress that whether you write it yourself or not, you'll likely end up with using a `struct`/`class`; e.g. [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is a templated `class`, `boost::hana::overload` is an object of a given `class`, and so on.

Since you haven't specified a standard, probably using Jeff Garrett solution is the way to go (though I'd change `vec.begin(), vec.end(),` to `vec,`, if you are to process the whole `vec`). If you have to be C++17 compliant, than you can use Range-v3:

```cpp
#include <range/v3/algorithm/equal_range.hpp>
// ...
const auto p2 = ranges::equal_range(vec, 2, std::less{},
    [](const S& s) { return s.number; });
```

which is ok for C++14 too, as long as you don't rely on [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

```cpp
const auto p2 = ranges::equal_range(vec, 2, std::less<>{},
    [](const S& s) { return s.number; });
```

Comment: I guess a lambda taking `auto&&` and a ladder of `if constexpr` checking type traits should also work? Not that I would consider it particularly good coding style, but for the sake of completeness I guess might also be worth mentioning.

Comment: @alagner, I'm not sure I've understood what you refer too. Probably you should post an answer. Notice that you can pass generic lambdas to `boost::hana::overload`, so you can also have a catch-all lambda...

Answer (score 1):

The ranges versions support projections:

```
std::ranges::equal_range(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 2, std::less{},
    [](const S& s) { return s.number; });
```